# How to determine the operating system of google compute engine is linux or windows?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I use python sdk of gcp to get compute engine list and I want to judge the  the operating system of google compute engine is linux or windows, but there is no any operating system informatioin in all fields of compute engine.

```
import sys
import json

from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import compute_v1


class VM:
    def __init__(self, cred_json_path):
        self.cred_json_path = cred_json_path
        self.credentials = self.create_credentials()
        self.page_size = 500

    def create_credentials(self):
        return service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(self.cred_json_path)

    def list_instance(self):
        compute_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient(credentials=self.credentials)
        results = []
        for _, instances in compute_client.aggregated_list(request={"project": self.credentials.project_id, "max_results": self.page_size}):
            for instance in instances.instances:
                # TODO 
                # I want to judge the operating system information for every instance is linux or windows here.
                results.append(instance)
        return results

    def show(self):
        instance_list = self.list_instance()
        for instance in instance_list:
            print(json.dumps(instance))


def main(cred_json_path):
    vm = VM(cred_json_path)
    vm.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Selcuk Ah, you're right.  Reopened.

Answer (score 0):

GCP SDK's compute_v1 seems to have a get_guest_attributes method. When attempting to use it:

```
compute_guest_data = compute_client.get_guest_attributes(project=GCPClass.project, zone=Zone, instance=obj)
```

I was able to retrieve:

- kind: "compute#guestAttributes"
- self_link:
  "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/prjname/zones/zonename/instances/instancename/guestAttributes/"
- variable_key: ""
- variable_value: "x86_64"

I'm not sure if the SDK allows setting the queryPath, it seems to me that get_guest_attributes should accept another parameter for queryPath/Key. For now, requests to the rescue, referencing the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/manage-guest-attributes#rest), I came up with:

```
url = (f"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{GCPClass.project}/zones/{Zone}/instances/{obj}/"f"getGuestAttributes?queryPath=guestInventory/LongName")
        auth_token = GCPClass.get_auth_token()
        os_info_response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"})
        if os_info_response.ok:
            data = os_info_response.json()
            guest_os = data.get("queryValue", {}).get("items", [{}])[0].get("value")
            print("Guest OS:", guest_os)
        else:
            print("Failed to retrieve guest attributes.")
            print(f"Status code: {os_info_response.status_code}")
```

This returned the guest os info properly.

Here's my get_auth_token for reference:

```
def get_auth_token(self): 
    scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"]
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(self.gcp_auth_data), scopes=scopes)
    request = Request()
    creds.refresh(request)
    return creds.token
```